# How to fix the crash caused by what UITableView's tableHeaderView height is too high

Tags: ios, objective-c

I set a UIWebView's view as the tableHeaderView of a UITableView, and the tableHeaderView's height (or the UIWebView's height) will change with the UIWebView's contentSize height.

The confuse thing is, when the height increase to 70,000 or above, will receive memory warning, and crash immediately.

What's the problem? And how to handle it without changing the logic?

Thanks very much.

Comment: 70k?? or 70.00 float?

Comment: 70k as the webview's contentSize height

Comment: That is toooooo much for height, that's why you are having a crash. Why do you want to add a UIWebView as a header? Usually webviews had a scroll in order to move up and dow, have you try to set the height to a fixed size for example 100? I'm just guessing what you do you wan to do